# how to access tomcat server from android app over usb cable?

Tags: android, usb

I have developed servlet on apache tomcat which is having mysql connectivity. and android client app. its working fine on emulator with url: http://10.1.10.203:8080/myServlet.
but now i want to deploy this app on actual device using usb cable. how i can i do this??
how to access ip of pc using android device over usb cable????

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the device Wi-Fi to connect to the same network where your PC is registered.

Comment: @poo123 You can use 3G or GPRS network to access your PC, but that would need you to configure your PC to be accessible from the outer world. Other than that, I do not think there are other options.